# Using Eigen Library in Netbeans

Tags: c++, netbeans, eigen

I am using Eigen library in C++. According to [Eigen documentation](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/GettingStarted.html):

> In order to use Eigen, you just need to download and extract Eigen's
>   source code (see the wiki for download instructions). In fact, the
>   header files in the Eigen subdirectory are the only files required to
>   compile programs using Eigen. The header files are the same for all
>   platforms. It is not necessary to use CMake or install anything.

So in Netbeans I added the directory of Eigen into the "include directories". Then I used a simple program as below (which is provided in Eigen documentation):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;

int main()
{
   Matrix3f A;
   Vector3f b;
   A << 1,2,3,  4,5,6,  7,8,10;
   b << 3, 3, 4;
   cout << "Here is the matrix A:\n" << A << endl;
   cout << "Here is the vector b:\n" << b << endl;
   Vector3f x = A.colPivHouseholderQr().solve(b);
   cout << "The solution is:\n" << x << endl;
}
```

Netbeans draws a red underline for colPivHouseholderQr() method!! In addition I can not see the colPivHouseholderQr() method under methods that can be called on object A.

Surprisingly, everything works fine and the program compiles and runs correctly although I have red underline for colPivHouseholderQr() !!

What can be wrong with my configurations ??

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [reported problem in the Netbeans when using Eigen](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=216095).

It fails to resolve many object identifiers, including member functions of templated objects such as your `colPivHouseholderQr()` function.

The best solution I arrived at was to use [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) instead.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `colPivHouseholderQr()` is in the QR module but you are only including the Dense module.

Try adding the following include:

```
#include <Eigen/QR>
```

See: [http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/api/group_*QR*_Module.html](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/api/group__QR__Module.html)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but if you check Eigen/Dense file, you can see that #include <QR> is there and there is no need to re-include it again.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry - this is more of a comment but I am unable to post comments - but did you try deleting the cache?  Dont know about windows but in Ubuntu its usually under 
~/.netbeans/7.0(or whatever)/var/cache - just delete everything under the cache directory.  Sometimes that works for me.

Comment: I checked it, but the cache folder of my Netbeans was empty.